# Why I can not use a 5.7 nor a 5.6 mysql docker image instead of mysql 8 with terraform in windows?

Tags: mysql, docker, window, terraform, terraform-provider-mysql

I am testing a `mysql_database` inside a `docker_container.mysql` using terraform in windows, but every time I try to use an image different from `mysql:8` inside the `docker_image.mysql` used by `docker_container.mysql`, terraform takes 5 minutes to create the `mysql_database` resource and throws the following error:

```
Error: Could not connect to server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

  on main.tf line 33, in resource "mysql_database" "test":
  33: resource "mysql_database" "test" {
```

And here is main.tf:

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"
}

resource "docker_image" "mysql" {
  name         = "mysql:8"
  //keep_locally = true
}

resource "docker_container" "mysql" {
  name    = "mysql"
  image   = docker_image.mysql.latest
        restart = "always"
  env     = [
    "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
  ]
  volumes {
    volume_name    = "mysql-vol"
    container_path = "/var/lib/mysql"
  }
  ports {
    internal = 3306
    external = 3306
  }
}

provider "mysql" {
  endpoint = "127.0.0.1:3306"
  username = "root"
  password = "root"
}

resource "mysql_database" "test" {
  name      = "test"
  depends_on = [docker_container.mysql]
}
```

I am testing mysql image tags shown at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql, specifically 5.6, 5.7 and 8, but only using mysql:8 seems to work Is there an other way in which I should reference those mysql image tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to verify the issue, and I observed the same error as yours only for mysql 5.7 and 5.6 when you keep the same `volumes`.

After **removing** the following section from the terraform script

```
   volumes {
     volume_name    = "mysql-vol"
    container_path = "/var/lib/mysql"
   }
```

and **removing** existing mysql docker images, mysql 5.6, mysql 5.7 and 8 worked as expected.

Btw, the error leading to failed connection was:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11
```

Comment: Checked that removing `volumes` makes other mysql versions work properly, but for some reason mysql 8 db creation is created much faster using `volumes` ~4s than without `volumes` ~40s, and that mysql 5.6 and 5.7 db creation without `volumes`, ~15s & ~16s respectively, are faster than mysql 8 without `volumes` ~40s, again